# Lagom / Akka readside Processor

Tags: akka-persistence, lagom

I have implemented a readside processor to put the processed events and maintain a read side cassandra table. However found that the event sourcing fails after some time with this error.

```
[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - com.syn.common.akka.message.drive.CItem; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2252861520543301684, local class serialVersionUID = -3725205170570257368
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.syn.common.akka.message.drive.CItem; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2252861520543301684, local class serialVersionUID = -3725205170570257368
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479) ~[scala-library-2.11.8.jar:1.0.4]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

The class for CItem has not changed from the beginning... However the readsideProcessor fails to de-serialise the events.. Few events are processed and stored it the table.

```
case class CItem(q: JsValue, a: JsValue, d: Option[JsValue])

object CItem {
  implicit val format: Format[CItem] = Json.format[CItem]
}


object UDSerializerRegistry extends JsonSerializerRegistry {
  override def serializers: Seq[JsonSerializer[_]] = Seq(
    JsonSerializer[CRecord]
  )
}
```

And CRecord Contains a list of CItems

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Followed something exactly similar to this:
https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/scala/ReadSideCassandra.html

Comment: I think you should post your code. I can't debug working documentation.

Comment: Did you update your play-json version?

Comment: Is this related to play-json serialization ? I thought it used the default binary serialization..

Comment: Binary serialization will be broken when the classes used in your case class change. Pretend your case class uses fields from any other library and you bumped the version of that lib.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing arises when there's a binary incompatibility when (de)serializing messages in akka-persistence.

Given that your message uses play-json in its fields (which I strongly do not recommend), it is likely that the version of play-json used in your project was changed and this broke your message class's binary compatibility.

To avoid this, I would refactor your code to not using play-json in your messages' fields. It couples you tightly to a JSON library which is used internally in Lagom, so you might run into shading issues when Lagom is upgraded, or more pragmatically, this binary compatibility issue.

In the case you decide to refactor your events, you can find a guide to event schema migration [here](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/scala/Serialization.html#Schema-Evolution).

Comment: Is it possible to add a deserializer to handle the previous events? Or do I need to do a complete migration ?

Comment: I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: So adding a custom  ( de )-  serializer will ensure that the new events are saved correctly. Old events need to be migrated right ?  
I can see the events are stored in binary format in Journal

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You can use Lagom's serialization mechanisms, but you need to treat migration very carefully. Events are just like any other public API: once you start making changes, your users/subscribers will know.

Comment: Ohhk,
Is there a way to read the current events in the Read Side Processor  (even if the binary compatibility is broken) ?

Comment: No. Binary incompatibility means "this class has a name I recognize but it is not the class I think it is" -- it's bytecode after all.